# webgl viewer/game engine for low poly turntables?

Tags: webgl, game-engine

I am looking for the best tool to achieve something like this (this is Blender's game engine, no real reflections, etc.) in an webgl viewer.

http://youtu.be/9-n12ZH5O6k

The idea is to prepare several basic scenes like this and then for the user to upload his design and have it previewed on a car (or other far more basic objects).

While p3d is nice, I don't think it does the job. There's no API for these cases yet. What are some options to pull this off? The requirement would be to have a library that doesn't have a too large footprint, since the feature/product is planned for the Asian market, so internet speed has to be considered.

Answer (score 0):

you should look into [three.js](http://threejs.org/)/[babylon.js](http://www.babylonjs.com/) maybe? But you surely won't achieve that app just by a fingersnap, so read the tutorials as well, but these libs will surely ease your task by much.